# How to fetch more claims from Facebook using Windows Azure ACS?

Tags: facebook, azure, acs

I am using Windows Azure ACS for facebook authentication in my application.

Azure by default gives 6 claims from facebook.

I need two additional claims DOB and Profile picture. How do I request these additional claims from Azure ACS?

Pls help. I can't seem to find any documentation on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't ask Azure to return more claims. What you can do is to use the claim value of "http://www.facebook.com/claims/AccessToken" which is one of the 6 claims from Azure.

Then send this accesstoken to facebook to get the other user permissions from Facebook. You can easily do this by using this tool: http://csharpsdk.org/